# Individual bits of Textbook RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa

This question relates to the underlying RSA assumption. Forgetting about the fact that Textbook RSA is deterministic, I am curious about the assumed strength of the RSA problem.

Does RSA hide all bits of the message, or are there some bits that can be easily revealed. Concretely,

$$m^e \space \bmod \space N$$

Can any part of $m$ be learned(with significant probability) without learning the secret key, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that $m$ is unknown to the adversary, and random in $[0,N-1]$, then to the best of our knowledge, $m^e\bmod N$ does not reveal anything about any bit of $m$ to an adversary unable to factor $N$.

Update: in the above, "bit of $m$" is in the sense of *binary digit* of $m$ (for some integer $k≥0$, the value of $⌊m/2^k⌋\bmod 2$), not *tiny amount of information*. Revealing $m^e\bmod N$ does reveal information abut $m$; most notably the adversary knows the [Jacobi symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) $\left(\frac m N\right)$ since that's also $\left(\frac{m^e\bmod N}N\right)$; and can test if an $x$ with $0≤x<N$ is $m$, by checking if $x^e\bmod N$ is $m^e\bmod N$.

Comment: One should clarify what a "bit" is here:  the RSA function is indeed known to leak (at least) one bit of information about $m$.  The conjecture that every bit is hardcore (which is how I interpreted your answer) would not contradict this.

Comment: If every bit is hardcore then how could it leak a bit of information. And what exactly is this information that it is known to leak?

Comment: @user4544: The Jacobi symbol of $m$ can be computed from $m^e \mod N$.

Comment: @DavidCash Thanks-you. To answer my original question then, none of $m$ can be recovered? So this would imply that if we apply RSA to a random $r$ then under RSA Assumption, no bit of $r$ can be recovered. And we can achieve IND-CPA PKE by using $r$ as in the one time pad--$r \space xor \space m$. This is a simpler scheme than any secure-RSA schemes i have seen, so I was skeptical.

Comment: @DavidCash: thanks for the note, the update was much needed.

Comment: @user4544:  It is conjectured that no bit of $r$ can be recovered (I think.)  But your PKE construction will not be IND-CPA secure, even if all input bits are hardcore for RSA.  This is because your scheme will leak the Jacobi symbol (and possible more information).  It was exactly this confusion that motivated my original comment above.

Comment: @DavidCash Got it. I see why it's not provably secure. At the end of the day though, were we able to show that each bit is a hard core bit would this not be a secure scheme?It leaks the Jacobi of $r$ but here $r$ is not the message and the only way to distinguish two messages is to recover a bit of $r$. The jacobi of $r$ leaks nothing about $m$. Yes by releasing the Jacobi of $r$ we are limiting the values that $r$ can take on, but only by a constant factor and a ppt adversary would not be able to check all valid $r$.

Comment: @user4544 If I know the Jacobi symbol of $r$, then I can distinguish $r\oplus 0^n$ from $r\oplus 1^n$ with non-negligible probability.  But if one wants to explore practical implications (at the end of the day), then that scheme has even bigger problems, like complete CCA insecurity.

Comment: @DavidCash Now I see! Thank you for your patience in showing me!